# when is android bitmap memory free'd when not using inPurgable?

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, heap-memory

Recently the android platform guidelines for inPurgable was updated, and it now recommends against using the inPurgable flag.

We used to decode byte arrays with inPurgable and inInputSharable set (on byte arrays). I've tried migrating this over to using inBitmap, and it works, but we run OOM far more than we did before.

I've tried doing this as an experiment (in the inBitmap code, when we cant find an image to use for inBitmap and need to create a new one):

```
try {
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetOptions.outWidth, targetOptions.outHeight, decodeConfig);
} catch (OutOfMemoryException e) {
    lruCache.clear();
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(targetOptions.outWidth, targetOptions.outHeight, decodeConfig);
}
```

And it doesn't work, including when there are bitmaps in the lrucache, which is confusing to me.

With inPurgable set the GC will free references to bitmaps under memory pressure, when is bitmap memory freed when not using inPurgable?

Comment: A guess is that bitmap allocation doesn't trigger a GC_FOR_ALLOC. If that's the case I guess there is no way to know when bitmap memory is freed... We use the bottom part of a bitmap lru cache for inBitmap recycling. So I guess the only fix for us is to reduce the cache size.. and never being 100% certain we won't crash :(